# Is this a real path? /path/to/something.ext

Tags: path

Ok, I have instructions to i.e. `export ABC=[/path/to/something.ext]` in the command prompt in linux.

Is this a real path or do I need to add my own path in???  I see these "`/path/to/..`" statements pretty common and thought it could actually lead to the file immediately.

Comment: you add your own path... ABC should also be replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an example path.  You'd find the path that makes sense on your system. You would not use the brackets though.  Obviously you could check on your system, `ls /path/to/something.ext` and ls would tell you the file didn't exist.